# Multiple Processors and Ram

Tags: central-processing-unit

Currently we have a hosted server that has one multi-core processor. We are looking at purchasing servers and one of the options is to add an additional processor (So there would be TWO multi-core processors).

Upon selecting the box for an additional processor I notice two things. 
1) The amount of RAM slots is doubled.
2) An even number of dimm slots must be used.

So my questions are:

1. Will CentOS / PHP / MySQL utilize both processors or is this kind of setup designed for VPS type systems?
2. If the system has 32GB of Ram in two 16GB slots can all 32GB be utilized at once or will each application only be able to use 16GB?

Comment: Of course the system will use them ...it doesn't matter at all how the hardware is laid out. It doubles because of the requirements of the board (slots must be identical on both processor buses).

Comment: Okay thanks so much. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1.Will CentOS / PHP / MySQL utilize both processors or is this kind of setup designed for VPS type systems?

So long as they're modern or even relatively-modern versions they'll use many, many threads/cores - some systems start hitting diminishing-returns at around 160-240 threads but I'm assuming you'll be nothing close to that many.

> 2.If the system has 32GB of Ram in two 16GB slots can all 32GB be utilized at once or will each application only be able to use 16GB?

They can be utilised yes but you shouldn't do that, you should try to have the same amount, and ideally type/size, of memory split evenly between processors i.e. 32GB on CPU 1 and 32GB on CPU 2 or similar. Leaving them on one server works but won't give you optimal performance.